# How to configure Nginx reverse proxy in Docker

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I'm trying to configure Nginx as reverse proxy for my docker container but doesn't work with environment variables.

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: tmc_nginx_ctnr
    ...
    env_file: .nginx/.env.local
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
  authentication:
    container_name: tmc_authentication_ctnr
    ...
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - '8002:8000'
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine3.17
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache curl openssl
COPY ./env_vars.sh /
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
COPY ./nginx-data/configs /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf/
COPY ./nginx-data/certs /etc/ssl/certs/custom/
EXPOSE 80 443
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

authentication.conf:

```
upstream authentication {
  server ${HOST_AUTHENTICATION_NAME}:8000;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name authentication.${SERVER_NAME} *.authentication.${SERVER_NAME};
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/custom/localhost.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/custom/localhost.key;
  location / {
    proxy_pass https://${HOST_AUTHENTICATION_NAME}:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name authentication.${SERVER_NAME} *.authentication.${SERVER_NAME};
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

env_vars.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
export ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}
export SERVER_NAME=${SERVER_NAME}
export HOST_AUTHENTICATION_NAME=${HOST_AUTHENTICATION_NAME}
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
envsubst < /env_vars.sh
nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

I'm trying to get the environment variables from the .env.local file by passing them to envsubst so I can use it in the authentication.conf file to point dynamically but I get this error.

> 2023/04/19 13:47:05 [emerg] 8#8: unknown "host_authentication_name" variable

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: 8000 is django's port. You configured nginx to listen to 80. You named server as `authentication.localhost` while trying to reference `authentication.local`.